# Storing multiple double numbers without an array

Tags: java

So for the problem the user will enter as many double numbers as the want until they enter a negative number then it will stop the loop.

However I don't know how I would store all these numbers since I don't know how many the user will input and I can't use an array for this problem.

Comment: Hi, could you show what you've done so far?

Comment: Look into the List interface.

Comment: @MadPhysicist And of course especially its implementations!

Comment: It's unclear what problem you need to solve in the first place. From your description, you don't need to store anything. Just let the user enter numbers, and stop the loop when it's negative. So all you need to know is the value of the last entered number.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a **List** as such:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<Double> allValues = new ArrayList<>();
        double enteredValue;

        do{
            System.out.println("Enter a value");
            enteredValue = keyboard.nextDouble();
            allValues.add(enteredValue);
        } while (enteredValue >= 0);
    }
```